# Update Data source PivotTables VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to update the data source of a collection of PivotTables that share the same data source...

I tried the next code

```
For Each pt In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PivotTablesSheet").PivotTables
         pt.ChangePivotCache ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
            (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Worksheets("SourceSheet").UsedRange)
            
         pt.RefreshTable
Next pt
```

It seems to work fine with one single PivotTable, but the problem begins when there are more than one. I can no longer connect them back to the Slicers because they don´t appear in the Caché (or whatever) as if the PivotTables didn't share the same data source, but they totally do! (I try to connect them manually but the slicers don't appear in the list)

I don't know why this happens.

Anyone have any solution to go around this very idiotic bump in the road?

Maybe there's another solution to update the data source of a PivotTable

Comment: You could convert your range to a table and then create the pivot from the table data source which will always remain up-to-date on the full data set. As data is added, all you would need to do is refresh the pivots and everything will update accordingly

Comment: I wonder if turning off refresh would help here. So, turn off refresh, loop through pivots to change data source, then turn refreshing back on once complete. This way, no pivot is updated (thus breaking the slicer) until ALL pivot sources are consistent.